# How to execute external PHP script in command line from your browser

Tags: php, linux

I have an external php script named `external.php` which includes this:

```
<?php
echo 'External Output';
?>
```

When I run that on command line with command:

```
php external.php
```

I get output as

```
External Output
```

But when the same script I execute from my browser's php file named `index.php` which has this code:

```
<?php
$exe=exec('php external.php',$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Then I get no output.

When I modify it as:

```
<?php
$exe=exec('php external.php 2>&1',$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Then I get this output:

```
php: /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by php)
```

My question is, how can I execute that "*external.php*" file in commandline from index.php and get output on my browser (i.e. on index.php) ? I have tried system() function too, it doesn't work as well.

**Edit:**
I cannot `include` the external.php in index.php because external.php can take lot of time to execute (more than 10 hours).

**Edit#2**
Solved it, giving the full path to PHP solved the problem.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$exe=exec('full/path/to/php /full/path/to/external.php',$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Thankyou Oleg and Scopey for giving me some hint help.

Comment: why don't you just `include()` the other php file?

Comment: because I need to execute it from the commandline, not on the browser because it can run up to days...

Comment: I have no clue why you're using exec to run a php file. Use include or require.

Comment: @CandiceWilliams you're already executing index.php from the command line. you can `include()` the other one inside index.php...

Comment: Even if you want to use the command line, include the file for the browser.

Comment: Using commandline because the external.php can take days to execute...

Comment: It's still going to take days to execute even if you call it from `exec`.

Comment: Yes but its going to run in background, so thats not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the full path of external.php:

```
<?php
$exe=exec('php /full/path/to/external.php',$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Try also specifying the full path to php on the command line and check that it works:

```
$/usr/bin/php "/full/path/to/external.php"
```

If that works, try it also in your php file:

```
<?php
$exe=exec('/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/external.php',$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Comment: @CandiceWilliams - Strange. Added another possible fix in my answer. Just guessing here, since I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Oleg Hi , i have a post on SO can you please take a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331958/how-to-execute-script-in-silent-mode-to-get-rid-from-browser-hang-on

Answer (score 0):

Try running `phpinfo()` from the command line. Often installations of PHP use a different PHP.ini for CLI usage. Running `phpinfo()` will show you the location of the ini file in use. It appears as though this ini might not be configured properly for your installation (as a guess)